# rethinkdb CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING was not declared in this scope error

Tags: rethinkdb

I am working on installing rethinkdb on my server, which is a CentOS 6.9 machine. I followed all the directions for a CentOS server as described [here](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install/centos/) for CentOS 6. I got all the way to the command `scl enable devtoolset-2 -- make` but while building, on line 244 of 421, the line that reads `build/release/obj/extproc/http_job.o` I receive the error "CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING was not declared in this scope"

I don't know what this means or why the error is popping up, but I can't continue with the build process as long as that error is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an obscure article that mentions a fix for this particular error. If you go into the rethinkdb folder on the server, you can then navigate to src/extproc/http_job.cc and open that file in a text editor. You can then search for the function `void set_default_opts` and inside of that function is the line `exc_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "", "PROTOCOLS);` If you just change `CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING` to `CURLOPT_ENCODING, you will be able to continue the build process. It worked for me.